# Secured HTML to PDF

Tags: html, pdf

I have an online book, but like to have it in PDF (readable without internet).
When I visit the website, I have to login to open the online book

Thing is: when I try to convert the index.html; it shows the login-page.

Is it possible to get around this page or to download it somehow from the webpage?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely **Download** the pdf after opening it !!

or If you want to download index.html page - Right click and select download source file in computer - if you are using mobile ! you can use other apps from app store | and download

Enjoy!